# How to set "isTrusted" to true (simulate MouseEvent)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, bots

I'd like to change originalEvent > MouseEvent > isTrusted to true, so it's not possible to detect if an event was triggered through jQuery. In General you can do this like this (clientX and clientY works perfectly fine):

```
$('#name').trigger({
    originalEvent: new MouseEvent('click', {
        clientX: 541,
        clientY: 346,
        isTrusted: true
    }),
    type: "mousedown"
});
```

I detect the event like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('name');

$(element).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    console.log(e);

    if (e.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
        console.log('real click');
    } else {
        console.log('programmatic click'); // shows this message
    }
});
```

I know that isTrusted is just "enumerable" so I am open to other suggestions too.